# Bluedroid: How to send LL_CONNECTION_UPDATE_REQ

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-source, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to force send a LL_CONNECTION_UPDATE_REQ to a slave with some specific connection parameters. How do I achieve this in Bluedroid? Is it possible from Bluedroid?

Target: AOSP v5.1+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling function `btsnd_hcic_ble_upd_ll_conn_params()` [in l2c_ble.c]
Function is defined in hciblecmds.c

If slave and master both support `Connection Parameter Update Procedure` defined in `9.3.9` in `BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 4.2` spec and declared in `LL_FEATURE_REQ (2.4.2.9)` and `LL_FEATURE_RSP (2.4.2.10)`, Link layer sends `LL_CONNECTION_PARAM_REQ (2.4.2.16)`.

If either of hosts don't support this feature, LL sends `LL_CONNECTION_UPDATE_REQ 2.4.2.1`

From `9.3.9.2 Conditions` in `BLUETOOTH SPECIFICATION Version 4.2`:

> A Central initiating the connection parameter update procedure shall use the
>   Link Layer Connection Update procedure defined in [Vol. 6], Part B Section
>   5.1.1 with the required connection parameters if either the Central or the
>   Peripheral does not support the Connection Parameters Request Link Layer
>   Control procedure.
>
> If both the Central and Peripheral support the Connection Parameters Request
>   Link Layer control procedure, then the Central or Peripheral initiating the
>   connection parameter update procedure shall use the Connection Parameters
>   Request Link Layer Control procedure defined in [Vol. 6], Part B Section 5.1.7
>   with the required connection parameters.

Although I'd add here that `btsnd_hcic_ble_upd_ll_conn_params()` only takes min and max connection intervals and uses them as a *hint*.

<strike>In my experience, when a range of values is passed, LL chooses any value within the range.</strike>

I have only done limited testing, so I am  not sure if LL will ALWAYS choose from supplied range, or can it choose from outside this range in some conditions, e.g. if an already connected slave has CI outside this range

From  `5.1.1 Connection Update Procedure`, LL will **always** choose Connection interval from range supplied by host. 
Thanks @Emil for pointing this out.

Comment: The controller shall not choose a connection interval outside the supplied range.

Comment: @Emil any reference for this in Spec? I have a hunch this is correct, but I couldn't find it in spec. Didn't look too hard though.

Comment: In the spec: "The Link Layer of the master shall determine the connInterval from the interval range given by the Host (connInterval_min and connInterval_max). The Link Layer shall indicate to the Host the selected interval value." With the normal definitions of "shall", that means "must".